Why does the encoder output latent variable shape of AutoencoderKL differ from the decoder input latent variable shape?
from diffusers import AutoencoderKL
import torch
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
vae = AutoencoderKL.from_pretrained("../model")

image = Image.open("../2304_10752.png").resize((512, 512))
image = transforms.ToTensor()(image).unsqueeze(0)
print(image.shape)
out = vae.encoder(image*2-1)
print(out.shape)
out = vae.decoder(out)
print(out[0].shape)
out = out[0].permute(1, 2, 0).detach().numpy()
out = (out * 255).astype("uint8")
out = Image.fromarray(out)
out.show()

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [512, 4, 3, 3], expected input[1, 8, 64, 64] to have 4 channels, but got 8 channels instead
I downloaded and loaded the vae part of the stable diffusion model in huggingface separately.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python?Rust?React? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Also from [tag:huggingface]: "Please ALWAYS use the more specific tags; huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets if your question concerns one of those libraries." Thus, edit in those as well if you are using any specific libraries.

I should use vae.encode and vae.decode not vae.encoder or vae.decoder

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
